# What is the significance of $ and {} in `find ${x} *`

Tags: find

I have the following :

```
x=/
find ${x} *
```

Now this is similar to  `find / *`

What is the significance of `$` and `{}` in `find ${x} *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$...` denotes a variable, and when followed by curly parenthesis `${...}`, you provide a boundary for the variable so you can run it next to a string literal like:

```
$ FLAVOUR="cheese"
$ echo "I like ${FLAVOUR}y crisps"
I like cheesey crisps
```

Without the parenthesis, you would see:

```
$ echo "I like $FLAVOURy crisps"
I like  crisps
```

Which, while true, isn't what you really wanted.

*Why* it's used in your example is beyond me. It isn't required.

---

Curly braces are [also used for bash array lookups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/bash-why-do-we-need-curly-braces-in-variables) when you want to specify the index, but this has nothing to do with your example:

```
$ arr=(*)
$ echo ${arr[3]} # print third item; 1-indexed? blimey.
jumbo-small.jpg
$echo ${arr[@]} # print whole array
glyphicons-halflings.png glyphicons-halflings-white.png jumbo.jpg jumbo-small.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, that answer my question. Since I am a beginner so just playing around. Agreed find ${x} * is not required, however was trying to understand the deeper meaning.